# Windows Forms Graphics.Drawstring avoid wrapping at hyphen

Tags: .net, printing

I have to print out a tabular document, each line is composed of numbers and text columns. The text in a text column may contain identifiers like 1K2016-000345 containing a hyphen. I am using Graphics.MeasureString and Graphics.Drawstring to determine the width and height of the rectangle necessary to display the text in the column, so it can also be multiline. Unfortunately sometimes the above identifiers, if they are the last word in the line, get wrapped at the hyphen which makes the identifier difficult to read.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior? Either somehow mark the identifier as a whole or the hyphen as not wrappable?

Comment: If the data is "tabular" then it gets to be pretty important to place the columns yourself.  If you don't then columns won't line up.  Unless you use a fixed-pitch font and, well, ugh.

Comment: Thank you Hans. I do position the columns of course and I am using proportional fonts. The listing is a "Kassajournal" containing a running number, date  & time, type, document identifier, description, and three more money columns. Everything fits perfectly with left/right alignment. Only in the description column I have the problem that the text is sometimes longer that the column width so that I have to wrap the text into an additional line. But if the description contains a document id with a hyphen then it gets hyphenated in the middle of the document id.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a overload of `Graphics.MeasureString()` that takes a `StringFormat` parameter and set the `FormatFlags` property of that `StringFormat` to `StringFormatFlags.NoWrap`:

```
g.MeasureString(text, font, origin, new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap));
```

Comment: Thank you Rene. I tried your suggestion to measure string with NoWrap flag. If I print with that flag then only the first part of the text gets printed out and it gets cut off at the hyphen.

Comment: @pb_SKAT I'm currently afk but I think there's another flag `NoClip`  that may solve this. I'll check tomorrow (utc+1 here, same for you I guess)

Comment: @pb_SKAT guess you need the same flags for `DrawString` too (not only `MeasureString`)

Comment: Thank you @Rene. Yes I do `g.MeasureString` to detect whether I will need more than 1 line in order to calculate the position of the next line and then I use `g.DrawString` with the same settings (`fmt.Alignment.Near` and `fmt.StringTrimming.Word`). With regard to the description on MS pages I hoped `TrimmingWord` would do what I need but there is no information about what **_word_** means in this context and how it could be influenced.

Comment: @pb_SKAT did you try [`StringFormatFlags.NoClip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) in combination with `NoWrap`? Seems _trimming_ is not your problem, but _wrapping_ and _clipping_.

Comment: Cheers @Rene. Yes I tried NoClip as well. If you read the flag descriptions at [(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx)] then there is obviously no flag doing what I need. The closest woult be `StringTrimming.Word` but the the entity word sould be definable. So eventually I wrote a 5-lines-of-code function using array.Split and Join to split the text at true word boundaries and I do a DrawString for each line. Anyway thank you for your efforts, I really appreciate.